# Intercept File Path from Windows Application

Tags: python, c++, windows, file

I was wondering if there was a way to intercept an application's call to the file system in order to perform asset resolution. For example, if an application requests a file such as `T:\Some\Path\f.txt` that proceeds as normal, but if in that application I pass a string such as `[BaseDrive][ProjectAssetFolder][ProjectAssetFile]` I'd want to intercept that call and process it into a regular file path.

The idea is to have a single point whereby I can perform this asset resolution, rather than writing resolvers for every application using their APIs.

Comment: If possible, that would be a horrible security exploit possibly.

Comment: "[BaseDrive][ProjectAssetFolder][ProjectAssetFile]" is not a fully-qualified DOS or device path, so this can't be implemented as a file-system filter in the kernel because the user-mode runtime library will normalize the path based on the process current working directory. You'd have to hook user-mode API functions such as `CreateFileW` in every process. OTOH, if you implement your own device such as "\\?\AssetManager", you're free to handle its namespace however you want. There is a material cost, however, to sign the device driver for the sake of security.